# Recursively add suffix after extension to all files in a directory

Tags: encryption, extension, recursive

**I had a ransomware attack** and all files were encrypted.

The encryption added a suffix to all the files after the extension for example `123.jpg` became `123.jpg.[xyz@gmail].xyz`

**I got the key** and decrypted the files.

The key looks for the suffix and the encryption key in the file to unlock it.  Once decrypted the suffix comes off.

**The problem is** some files were encrypted twice, so I need to run the key a second time but since they don't have the suffix the key does not work.

I need to go and add the `[xyz@gmail].xyz` to all the files regardless of their extension so I can run the key a second time.

Comment: What Operating System are you running? Windows 10?

Comment: Also, may I ask how you got the key? Did you have to pay the ransom for it or did they use a form of encryption where the decryption or private key or whatever was stored locally?

Comment: Yes I paid.  The attack was on windows 7 and NAS attached to the network.  Now I am on windows 10

Comment: @LabMan How did the ransomware get on your system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the below command in PowerShell

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object `
   { Rename-Item $_.FullName $($_.BaseName + ".[xyz@gmail].xyz") -WhatIf }
```

The `-WhatIf` option is to do a dry run. After checking that the new names are correct, just remove `-WhatIf` to do the real rename. The equivalent shortened version is

```powershell
ls -Fi -R | % { ren $_.FullName $($_.BaseName + ".[xyz@gmail].xyz") -wi }
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked!  Been busy recovering to thank you earlier :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the ***FREE*** top 5 Windows utilities I use is called ***"Bulk Rename Utility"***. You have the option of selecting one or more files and can also do high powered regex search and replace. It can be downloaded from https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/

It looks daunting at first, but you will quickly understand how it works and you can quickly do very simple tasks, or if needed extremely complex ones too. It is truly *FREE*. No trials, nag screens or crippled ware. The full functioning program is *FREE*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you I tried that but it makes the change before the extension and not after for example if I add suffix abc to file xxxx.jpg, it becomes xxx.abc.jpg.  I need to make it xxx.jpg.abc

Comment: I don't have a windows machine in front of me at this moment but look at item 11 "extension". There is also a way for it to treat the extension inclusive in search and replace but I do not rember how I did that a few years ago.